# WordPress (TwentyThirteen vs. TwentyTen): Admin Panel: What happened to the Edit Post page Excerpt pane?

Tags: wordpress

In the TwentyTen theme you could click on a post and there was a box called Excerpt.
What happened to it. Was it completely removed, and if so why, or is the same
functionality still there but available in a different place, or is that
functionality still implemented but in a different way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the Excerpts pane, on the "Posts -> Add New" page of the admin panel, click
on the "Screen Options" slideout on the top right of the page (below the black admin
toolbar at the top), and from the options that slide out click on Excerpt.

Regards.